# Probability of at least one event occuring

Tags: probability

Let $A$ and $B$ be events with $P(A) = p_1$ and $P(B) = p_2$ and $p_1 + p_2 \in (0,1)$.

What is minimum and maximum probability of at least one event occuring if both of them are performed successively?

If $A$ and $B$ are mutually exclusive, then $P(A \cup B) = P(A) + P(B) = p_1 + p_2$ which is the max. Otherwise $P(A \cup B) = p_1 + p_2 - P(A \cap B)$ and $P(A \cap B) = P(A|B) \cdot P(B) = P(B|A) \cdot P(A)$. Obviously $P(A|B) \leq 1$, same for $P(B|A)$, so the minimum should be $p_1 + p_2 - \max\{p_1,p_2\}$, right?

If $p_1, p_2 \in (0,1)$, then the max would be $1$ (as they might not be mutally exclusive) and the minimum as described above. Is this correct?

Comment: Should $p_1 + p_2 \in (0,1)$ actually be $p_1, p_2 \in (0,1)$? If not, $p_1 + p_2$ doesn’t have a max, but its supremum is 1.

Comment: $$\begin{align*}P(A \cup B) &= p_1 + p_2 - P(A \cap B) \\ &\ge p_1 + p_2 - \min\{p_1, p_2\} \\&= \max\{p_1, p_2\}\end{align*}$$since the most that $P(A \cap B)$ can be is $\min\{p_1, p_2\}$. In your problem though, it seems like $p_1, p_2$ can be arbitrarily small, so that the infimum is 0.

Comment: @Joe Thanks, I've mistakenly put the max at the spot instead of the min which is the right one. $p_1$ and $p_2$ are fixed probabilities with one of them potentially being $0$ but definitely fixed values, so that min and max exist.

Comment: You’re welcome. But if $p_1$ and $p_2$ are fixed, then you shouldn’t conclude “the max would be 1”, like you do at the end. The max would be $p_1 + p_2$, which might be less than 1.

Comment: @Joe You're right. The maximum probability should be $\min\{p_1 + p_2, 1\}$.